# How much memory allocated for node in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, struct, nodes

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

pointer->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

How many bytes of memory are dynamically given to `pointer->next` in the above code. For `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))`, 2 bytes are given. Likewise how many for `node`?

Comment: Write the code and check.

Comment: The answer depends very much on the target.  Why do you want to know this statically?

Comment: 2 bytes for a pointer?! Are you creating a 16-bit executable? Just had flashbacks of 1995.

Comment: @itsme86: `int` is not a pointer.

Comment: Please, somebody, explain me the upvotes...

Comment: What do you mean by _"how much"_? How much guaranteed by standard or how much is actually reserved by OS?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I cannot. But I also cannot explain downvote. Seems like children are playing with buttons...

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(node))` allocates `sizeof(node)`  bytes. Print the `sizeof(node)` value to find out how many. Note that the answer will be different on different compilers and even with different compiler settings.

Answer (score 2):

Malloc will dinamically assign the size of "node".

Node is a struct and the size of every struct depends on the size of every element inside the struct.

In this case, the size of node will be: size of int + size of struct Node*
(If the result is not multiple of 2, it will be padded for architecture reasons)
Your device has an architecture of 2 bytes, and for that reason, the size of the structs can only be 2, 4, 6, 8 etc...

The size of int depends on the target you are working on. Since your architecture is 16 bits, the size of int is 2 bytes.

About. the size of struct Node *, you need to know that EVERY pointer data types have exactly the same size, it doesn't matter the data type their are pointing to. And that size also depends on the architecture. Again, your architecture is 16 bits and that's why the size of struct node * is 2 bytes.

size of int = 2.

size of struct node * = 2

Total memory assigned by malloc = 2 + 2 = 4

Comment: This answer is mostly incorrect. Starting with this statement: *In this case, the size of node will be: size of int + size of struct Node*. There might be padding.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, starting earlier at line _"Malloc will dinamically assign the the size of "node""_ Size of "node" will be assigned (calculated) by compiler

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a lot about your system, we just can't tell you.  You can take that same code and try it on multiple compilers, and you'll get different answers.  You have to check yourself, using `sizeof(node)` or `sizeof(struct Node)` (I think either syntax works, but just in case).

Comment: Side note: once you know that number, NEVER hard-code it.  Always use `sizeof` to make sure it is correct by letting the compiler figure it out.

Comment: That should be `sizeof(node)` (with a lower case `n`).

Comment: I wrote it that way originally, but the question has it as 'N' so I changed it to upper case.

Comment: Really? I'm seeing `struct Node` and `typedef … node`, but I could be missing something.

Comment: Well, lets settle it with a compiler.  I tried it on mine, and it gave the same answer (16 bytes) using `Node` and `node`.  Either one works I guess.  I don't know if that'd be standard across all compilers/versions of C though.

Comment: My best guess then is that you're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @NisseEngström Yes it looks like this, but afaik today's even `C` compilers will register also `Node` in type system

Comment: @Cody: That should be `sizeof(node)` and `sizeof(struct Node)`, the latter with an upper case `N`. :-)

Comment: @NisseEngström I think newer C standards will do it either way as mvideglauz says, but thanks for catching that.  Better this answer conform to different versions of C.

Answer (score 1):

First, a suggestion: rewrite

```
pointer->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

as

```
pointer->next = malloc( sizeof *pointer->next );
```

You don't need the cast (unless you're working on a pre-ANSI implementation, in which case God help you), and using the dereferenced target as the operand of `sizeof` means you don't have to specify the type, potentially saving you some maintenance heartburn.

Also, a little whitespace goes a long way (although you don't need to put whitespace around the function arguments - that's my style, some people don't like it, but it makes things easier for me to read).

> How much bytes of memory is dynamically given to pointer->next

It will be *at least* as big as `sizeof (int)` plus `sizeof (struct Node *)`, and potentially may be bigger; depending on your platform, it could be as small as 4 bytes or as large as 16.  C allows for "padding" bytes between struct members to satisfy alignment requirements for the underlying architecture.  For example, a particular architecture may require that all multi-byte objects be aligned on addresses that are multiples of 4; if your `data` member is only 2 bytes wide, then there will be 2 unused bytes between it and the `next` member.